# moment generating function confusion

Tags: probability, statistics

On this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROpBZalIt3Q  at 0:42, he states that the moment generating function is the integral of $e^{tX}$ multiplied by the pdf of an exponential function. I don't understand this, I have defined as: $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) \ dx$ where $f(x)$ is pdf of $X$. So surely, we should have the moment generating function as $\int e^{tX}f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the PDF of $e^{tX}$ not the PDF of $X$ which is what he stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula is: If $X$ has pdf $f(x)$, then for any function $h(X)$
$$E[h(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x)f(x)\,dx.$$
When $h(X)=X$, you get the formula for expectation of $X$:
$$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx.$$
When $h(X)=e^{tX}$, you get
$$E[e^{tX}] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}f(x)\,dx.$$
In all cases  $f(x)$ is the pdf of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I can motivate this with a simple example using a discrete random variable.  Let $X$ be a random variable with probability distribution $$\begin{align*} \Pr[X = 0] &= 1/5, \\ \Pr[X = 1] &= 1/3, \\ \Pr[X = 3] &= 7/15. \end{align*}$$  Note that the support of $X$ is $\mathcal X = \{0,1,3\}$ as there are the only possible values of $X$ and the probabilities add up to $1$.

Now if I ask for the expectation of $X$, you would compute $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \sum_{x \in \mathcal X} x \Pr[X = x] = 0 \cdot \Pr[X = 0] + 1 \cdot \Pr[X = 1] + 3 \cdot \Pr[X = 3] = \frac{1}{3} + 3 \cdot \frac{7}{15} = \frac{26}{15}.$$  This much is clear--the expectation is in a sense a weighted average of all possible outcomes of $X$, weighted by the probabilities of those outcomes.

If I now ask what is the expectation of $2^X$, then what this means is the weighted average of $2^X$, weighted by the same probabilities:  $$\operatorname{E}[2^X] = 2^0 \Pr[X = 0] + 2^1 \Pr[X = 1] + 2^3 \Pr[X = 3] = \frac{23}{5}.$$  The probabilities of each $X$ remains the same; it is merely that the function to be averaged is $2^X$ instead of $X$ itself.

So, in the case where $X$ is a continuous random variable, we can see that the sum over the support of $X$ is replaced by an integral, and the probability mass function is replaced by a density function:  $$\Pr[g(X)] = \int_{x \in \mathcal X} g(x) f_X(x) \, dx.$$  This is the informal motivation for the expectation of a function of a random variable.  It is worth noting that because in general $$\int_{x \in \mathcal X} g(x) f_X(x) \, dx \ne g\left( \int_{x \in \mathcal X} x f_X(x) \, dx \right),$$ we should take care to remember that $$\operatorname{E}[g(X)] \ne g(\operatorname{E}[X]).$$